# Given an array, use a function to sum up certain values depending on a different value in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am given a campgrounds array and I first need to determine which campgrounds are reserved or not, (`isReserved: false`). I then need to take the `partySize` of those campgrounds and add them together.

Here is the campground array:

```
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

Here is what I have so far: (I am very new to Javascript, I'm sure you can tell from my code)

```
function additionalCapacity(campgrounds) {
  let openCampsites = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    let currentCampsite = campgrounds[i];
    
    if(currentCampsite.isReserved === false) {
      openCampsites.push(currentCampsite);
    } 
    openCampsites.reduce(additionalCapacity, 0);
  }
  return openCampsites;
}
```

I created an empty array and put the unreserved campgrounds inside, and tried to use the `reduce()` method to add them, but it is not working. How can I add up the values?

Comment: this is not how you use `.reduce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1- Using reduce():**

To use `reduce`, you first need to define the function that will be used to calculate the total to be returned by the reduce method, for example the [MDN reference for reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) uses this example to sum up the values:

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
total =  myarrray.reduce(reducer);
```

What you want to do is sum up the total *of the `partySize` value* in each array in your `openCampsites` array, so we can do that by accessing the partySize of the current value in the sum function using `currValue.partySize`, e.g.

```
const calcCapacity = (accumulator, currValue) => accumulator + currValue.partySize;
capacity =  openCampsites.reduce(calcCapacity, 0);
```

Note that you also want to do this *after* you have filled your array, so move the call to reduce to after the `for` loop.

**Working Example** using reduce()

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

/* define the function to calculate the capacity in the reduce method 
  Note - this must be included in the js before the call to the method */
const calcCapacity = (accumulator, currValue) => accumulator + currValue.partySize;


var cap = additionalCapacity(campgrounds);
console.log("capacity="+cap);

function additionalCapacity(campgrounds) {
  let openCampsites = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    let currentCampsite = campgrounds[i];
    
    if(currentCampsite.isReserved === false) {
      openCampsites.push(currentCampsite);
    } 
  }
  capacity =  openCampsites.reduce(calcCapacity, 0);
  return capacity;
}
```

**Method 2 - Simply sum up the total in the loop:**

Note that if this is all you want to do in the `additionalCapacity` function, you are overcomplicating it - you could just keep a running total as you loop through the array, e.g.

```
function additionalCapacity(campgrounds) {
  var capacity = 0;   // initialise our variable to keep the running total

  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {  
    /* if the campground at [i] (note, we do not need a separate var - we can use campgrounds[i] directly)
       is not reserved (note: ! is the logical NOT operator)
       then get the value of partySize for this campground and 
       add it to the existing value of capacity  (note += is shorthand for capacity = capacity + newvalue
    */ 
    if(!campgrounds[i].isReserved) 
      capacity += campgrounds[i].partySize;  
  }
  return capacity;
}
```

This introduces a number of new features you may not be familiar with yet as you are only learning (e.g. logical NOT operator, the `+=` shorthand) , so I have added explanations in the comments.

**Working Example** simply summing up the total in the loop

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

var capacity = additionalCapacity(campgrounds);
console.log("capacity="+capacity);

function additionalCapacity(campgrounds) {
  var capacity = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {    
    if(!campgrounds[i].isReserved)
      capacity += campgrounds[i].partySize;
  }
  return capacity;
}
```

Notes on some of the reduced code:

- we do not need a separate variable for `campgrounds[i]` - we can use campgrounds[i] directly e.g. `campgrounds[i].isReserved`
- `!` is the [logical NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) to test the value of a variable and returns true if the variable is false
- We can use `+=` as shorthand for adding values , e.g. `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`

Comment: Wow, I really was overcomplicating it. Thank you for giving me several examples, it actually makes sense now!!

Comment: @alexwhitmore Glad to help! When you are learning, you don't always know when there are simpler alternatives to the way you are using, so I always try to answer the question directly (because that is what you asked), and then give an alternative if I think there is one :)

Answer (score 0):

Your reduce function need to receive a callback(function) to work, for example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const sum = arr.reduce((acc, currentValue) => acc + currentValue)
console.log(arr) //output is 10
```

If I understood you right, you want to get the sum of all "Partysize" that are not reserved.

you can try this

```
function additionalCapacity(campgrounds) {
    let sum = 0;
    campgrounds.forEach(c => {
        if (!c.isReserved) {
            sum += c.partySize;
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

The reduce, creating a new array and pushing items to it only to get the sum is unnecessary.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was definitely trying to overcomplicate it for no reason. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pass the result of `filter` to a `reduce` function. First we filter for campgrounds where is `isReserved` is `false`, and then we return the sum of those campgrounds' `partySize`.

```
let additionalCapacity = campgrounds
  .filter(({isReserved}) => isReserved === false )
  .reduce((a, b) => a + (b['partySize'] || 0), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This way you can use reduce to solve.**

> 1. For not reserver case (isReserved: false)

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

console.log(campgrounds.reduce( (acc, ele) => !ele.isReserved ? acc += ele.partySize : acc, 0));
```

> For reserved case (isReserved: true)

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

console.log(campgrounds.reduce( (acc, ele) => ele.isReserved ? acc += ele.partySize : acc, 0));
```